# How to create a 2d array with different column in C?

Tags: python, c

In Python I can have data:

`lst = [[1,2,3],[2,3],[1,2,3,4]]`

and then accessed by lst[i][j].

How can I make this happen in C?

Answer (score 5):

You can do the same only by dynamically allocating memory for each row of the array and keeping the size of each row in some other array.
For example

```
int sizes[3] = { 3, 2, 4 };

int **a = malloc( 3 * sizeof( int * ) );

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
   a[i] = malloc( size[i] * sizeof( int ) );
}
```

Take into account that you will need to initialize each row manually.

In C++ you could initialize rows when they are allocated. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 3;
    size_t sizes[3] = { 3, 2, 4 };

    int **a = new int * [N];

    a[0] = new int[sizes[0]] { 1 ,2, 3 };
    a[1] = new int[sizes[1]] { 2, 3 };
    a[2] = new int[sizes[2]] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++ ) std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) delete [] a[i];
    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Though it would be better to yse container `std::vector`.

The output is

```
1 2 3 
2 3 
1 2 3 4
```

Also take into account that such arrays exist in C#.:)

Comment: your answer help me a lot, do I need to delete array a in C manual? I saw you delete it in C++ code.

Comment: @lessisawesome Yes, you will need to delete them after they will not be used any more. You should use standard C function free instead of the C++ operator delete.

Answer (score 4):

This should help you.

```
int lst[][4]={{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

Comment: +1, but you forget the type (`int`?), and there is a blank between `2,,3` in the OP code

Comment: I thought it would be printing mistake.
I don't know whether it would work in python as I'm not used to python.

Comment: yes, this is awesome, how to create it dynamic, another question my be lot of memory wasted if data is huge

Comment: you can use malloc or calloc for allocating memory dynamically

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int *array[] = {
        (int []){1,2,3},
        (int []){2,3},
        (int []){1,2,3,4}
    };
    int a_len[] = {3,2,4};
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a_len)/sizeof(*a_len);++i){
        for(j=0;j<a_len[i]; ++j){
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```